# Installing Gazebo & gazebo_ros_pkgs from source and hydro ROS from binaries

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Everybody, I need to run multiple turtlebots and get access of the Gazebo source code so that I can control the turtlebots. Currently I have installed both hydro ROS and 1.9 Gazebo from pre-compiled binaries. To get access the Gazebo&GazeboROSpkgs source code I need to reinstall Gazebo from the source. My questions are: Do I need to reinstall both ROS and Gazebo&GazeboROSpkgs from the source in order to keep them working properly?
or Do I just need to reinstall Gazebo&Gazebo_ROS_pack from the source and keep ROS as it is now(binaries)?.
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. Robert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6029/installing-gazebo-&-gazebo_ros_pkgs-from-source-and-hydro-ros-from-binaries/) by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Why do you need access to the source code to control the turtlebots?

If possible try to realize everything with plugins!

if you need a source install you do not need to install ros from source but you can might not be able to install the newest Gazebo(3.0) with Hydro because they are using different ubuntu version...

The installation instructions in the wiki should guide you through the whole installation process...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-04-24**:
Hi evilBiber, I need to use multiple turtlebots and have problems to publish topics such as "/odom" for each individual turtlebot. I remapped the topic name but nothing work. I read some posts here  where people recommend to fix it from the source code. In this particular case "/odom" was declared as "global name" and I need to change to "relative name" just "odom" so that it can take a namespace for each individual turtlebot. Do you think I can fix it without using the source code. Thanks

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2014-04-24**:
this is not directly in the gazebo source.... I'm using multiple quadcopters with `gazebo/gazebo_ros_pkg` installed from src. I quess you will only have to change the plugins not gazebo itself...

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-04-24**:
evilBiber, i am almost new on gazebo and when you said change the plugins these plugins are on the gazebo_turtlebot package as source code. I couldn't find anything on packs just urdf, launch, xml files.

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-04-24**:
Sorry, i didn't finish my comment. Please can you indicate me where I can change these plugins. Also when you said that you installed gazebo/gazebo_ros_pkg from src you meant from "source" Thanks!

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2014-04-24**:
Hi, I took a short look at the turtlebot but could not figure out the problem(would need more time)... it might be that it is enough to change some of the launch or xacro files. For me this seems to be a problem on ros side so might be a better idea to ask on ros answers for help...

**Comment by [Robert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/637/robert/) on 2014-04-24**:
Thanks evilBiber. I wiil ask on ros answer